# Example of continuous real valued functions

Tags: general-topology

Provide an example of continuous real valued functions, so
a map $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, that is open but not closed. Make sure to justify why
your example subsets satisfy the desired criteria

Given that: A map $f : X \to Y$ is called *open* if for every
open set $U$ in $X$, the set $f(U)$ is open in $Y$ and 
$f$ is called *closed* if it
maps closed sets in $X$ to closed sets in $Y$.

I am not sure if there has to be one function, or a set of functions being open and not closed

I need a start on this. Please help

Comment: You just need to construct a **Single** map which is open but not closed.What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm not sure such a map exists.

Comment: It is possible.  Why would one think a homeomorphism is impossible?  Can we avoid that.

Comment: Hint:  f(R) need not be R.

Comment: SPOILERS:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147879/continuous-functions-do-not-necessarily-map-closed-sets-to-closed-sets

Answer (score 3):

Hint: It's not hard to show that if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is open then it has to be strictly monotone.

Comment: How can such a map not be closed?

Comment: @fleablood That would spoil the fun for the OP, but it can be done.

Comment: It can?  ... Oh!  D'oh.  It can!  Hint.  An continuous monotone function will map limit points to limit points  So to map closed B to not closed C there must be a limit point of C that is not in C which is *not* mapped from a limit point in B. But it's not mapped from an interior of comp(B) either.  So....

Answer (score 0):

Continuous functions map closed sets to closed sets. So such continuous open but not closed function doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you sure?  That's actually not true.  Can f(B) have a limit point y where f^-1(y) is not a limit point of B?

Comment: Closed sets in R can be null set, R, interval (compact) or countable set. Since function is continuous, R is mapped to R for unbounded function, which is also closed. For bounded function R is mapped to a compact set. Null sets are mapped to null sets. Compact sets are mapped to compact sets. I can't think of any counterexample continuous functions.

Comment: "Since function is continuous, R is mapped to R for unbounded function"  Who said f is unbounded?

Comment: I considered both possibilities. Bounded and unbounded

Comment: "For bounded function R is mapped to a compact set."  Why do you think this?  Indeed that is certainly false.

Comment: Bounded and continuous.

Comment: f(x)= x/(|x| + 1) is bounded as -1 < f(x) < 1.

Comment: f(x) = 2^x.  f(R) = (0, infty).  Is not compact.

Comment: Oh. So can this be the answer. Since it maps every open set to open set and there is a closed set which is not mapped to a closed set